# Any limitations for data get or fetch from from GraphQL in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am very new in Bigcommerce. I have 400000 products it's possible to fetch all 400000 record from GraphQL at once. Or Any Limit in Bigcommerce or limit where I check limit of Bigcommerce in Bigcommerce.

Comment: Hey Abid, looks like this question is similar to your other submitted question. Take a look here for more info on catalog management via the api. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70877269/how-get-or-fetch-100000-record-from-graphql-or-api-of-bigcommerce

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely suggest checking out the link that Heather provided in her comment, but I will also answer your question directly.

The GraphQL API only supports up to 50 resources at a time, but this also depends on the complexity of your query - so it can vary. I'd highly suggest checking out the [BigCommerce GraphQL Overview](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/graphql/graphql-storefront-api-overview), as the documentation here goes over this exact question. If you are using the server-side API endpoints, there's a limit of **250** resources per response.