# How get or fetch 100000 record from GraphQL or API of bigcommerce

Tags: graphql, bigcommerce

I am new in Bigcommerce and I need to get or fetch 100000 record from GraphQL or Bigcommerce API of Bigcommerce.

Is this possible or any other way to get data.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer regagarding the BigCommerce Management API (not the Storefront GraphQL API). Both the v2 and v3 APIs default to 250 items if you don't otherwise specify your limit.

Both v2 and v3 accept `limit` and `page` querystring parameters that indicate your page size and which page you want.

In v2, you just keep requesting data while increasing your page number each time until you get an empty data response.

The v3 responses include a `meta` object that is helpful for pagination.

```
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "total": 2,
      "count": 2,
      "per_page": 2,
      "current_page": 1,
      "total_pages": 1,
      "links": {
        "next": "?sort=name&include=variants&limit=10&page=2",
        "current": "?sort=name&include=variants&limit=10&page=1"
      },
      "too_many": false
    }
  }
```

Therefore, fetching 100,000+ products, customers, etc is a matter of fetching up to 250 at a time.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference